# How to Insert empty string in amazon Redshift without getting converted to NULL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, bigdata

I am trying to load data using copy command in Redshift using pipe delimiter csv file, while loading `||` empty is getting converted to NULL as I wanted but `|""|` this also getting converted to NULL. How can I handel this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\copy (select * from schema.table) to 'path/filename.csv' NULL 'NULL' DELIMETER '|' CSV HEADER;` for exporting.

In Redshift I used `NULL as 'NULL'` option in the copy command it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have the EMPTYASNULL option enabled or have NULL AS '' for your COPY.  Either of these will convert empty strings to NULL during COPY.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

If neither of these options are selected then please post example commands and data.

Comment: yes i used EMPTYASNULL its required i cant ignore that, data will be separated by pipe delimetered like ||""| this should be copied as null,empty string but both are converting to null

Comment: EMPTYASNULL tells Redshift to always convert empty strings to NULL (for text values) when copying.  Quoting a columns does not imply a text value and isn't a hint about empty strings - any value in a CSV/PSV can be quoted.  Quotes are stripped before the data is cast and inserted into the table.  Both of the values you provided in your comment are empty values that need to be interpreted to the data type of the table.  If you need to import both NULLs and empty strings you will need to have different input data to represent these different values.

Comment: I am exporting data from postgress to csv/psv is the only option there as i know if i dont use EMPTYASNULL nulls are not loading as NULL if i use empty strings are getting converted how can i solve this issue assume data is in large scale like 100TB

Comment: When exporting from postgres you need to specify a value to be interpreted as NULL - like ***NULL***.  Then you specify NULL AS '***NULL***' to you copy command.  If your csv/psv doesn't have a clear differentiation between NULL and empty string then there is nothing Redshift can do to create one.

Comment: \copy (select * from schema.table) to 'path/filename.csv' DELIMETER '|' CSV HEADER;  This is my export command can you tell me how to interpret NULL to 'NULL'? Please give me the command

Comment: So it's the "select *" that you need to change.  First off it is generally not a best practice to use

Comment: So it's the "select \*" that you need to change.  First off it is generally not a best practice to use '\*' as this makes you column order dependent and this can be changed.  You will need to expand '*' to the column names and COALESCE() the values to your new NULL indication string.  Like "SELECT COALESCE(A, '\*\*\*NULL\*\*\*') as A, COALESCE(B, '\*\*\*NULL\*\*\*') as B ... FROM ...".  With this NULL will be exported as "\*\*\*NULL\*\*\*" but empty strings will still be "".  This way you can indicate the difference between these strings.

Comment: I used \copy (select * from schema.table) to 'path/filename.csv' NULL 'NULL' DELIMETER '|' CSV HEADER; for exporting and used NULL as 'NULL' option in copy command it worked